# R grep paste error in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

i have a problem on my dataframe. I am trying to score tweets based on different inputs.
All goes wel except for the last part.. i cannot figure out what is wrong.
My data frame consists out of tweets.

I put a lot of Holiday destinations into a vector and use grep(paste($COUNTRY$, collapse ="|") to search for it.
However the last one gives me this error:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "score", value = 10) : 
>     replacement has 1 row, data has 0

This is my code:

```
italiaans <- c("Rome", "venice", "Venezia", "Roma", "Florence", "Firenze","milan", "Città Metropolitana di Milano", "Milano", "naples", "napoli", "Bologna", "riccione", "bellaria-igea Marina","Selva Di Val Gardena", "Wolkenstein in Gröden", "Cattolica")
portugees <- c("coimbra", "azores", "aveiro", "evora" ,"porto", "madeira", "sintra", "obidos", "algarve", "lisbon","portugal", "brasilie", "brasil","Rio De Janeiro", "rio", "sao Paulo", "salvador", "florianopolis", "foz do iguacu", "buzios", "manaus", "jericoacoara", "curitiba", "gramado")
piete <- c("BuenosAires")
  totaltweetsScore[grep(paste(france, collapse="|"), totaltweetsScore$text, ignore.case=TRUE),]$score <- 1
  totaltweetsScore[grep(paste(turkey, collapse="|"), totaltweetsScore$text, ignore.case=TRUE),]$score <- 2
  totaltweetsScore[grep(paste(germany, collapse="|"), totaltweetsScore$text, ignore.case=TRUE),]$score <- 3
  totaltweetsScore[grep(paste(portugees, collapse="|"), totaltweetsScore$text, ignore.case=TRUE),]$score <- 4
  totaltweetsScore[grep(paste(Spain, collapse="|"), totaltweetsScore$text, ignore.case=TRUE),]$score <- 5
  totaltweetsScore[grep(paste(us, collapse="|"), totaltweetsScore$text, ignore.case=TRUE),]$score <- 6
  totaltweetsScore[grep('Holland', totaltweetsScore$text, ignore.case=TRUE),]$score <- 7
  totaltweetsScore[grep(paste(italiaans, collapse="|"), totaltweetsScore$text, ignore.case=TRUE),]$score <- 8
  totaltweetsScore[grep(paste(maleisie, collapse="|"), totaltweetsScore$text, ignore.case=TRUE),]$score <- 9
  totaltweetsScore[grep(paste(piete, collapse="|"), totaltweetsScore$text, ignore.case=TRUE),]$score <- 10
  totaltweetsScore[grep('NA', totaltweetsScore$text, ignore.case=TRUE),]$score <- NA
```

As you can see everything is just Copy paste... except for the name of which vector to use and the number to add..

How can i fix this error?
If i put in a other vector then Piete, like italiaans, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we don't have `totaltweetsScore` it's hard to reproduce your error, but try altering your search/replace patterns in general from `grep` and `]$score <-` to:

```
totaltweetsScore[grepl(paste(piete, collapse="|"), totaltweetsScore$text, ignore.case=TRUE), "score"] <- 10
```

and see if that makes a difference. I suspect `BuenosAires` is not in `totaltweetsScore`.

Comment: Strange enough it does solve my question.
I do not know why it did that... but hey it works!

Comment: Take a look at `?grep` and see what both `grep` and `grepl` return as values. That might give you a hint (but I'll be glad to explain if you want clarification).

Comment: Seems to me that grepl returns also when something DOESNT match.. and Grep gives an error when theres no match.

Comment: Right, so if there's no match in your original `grep` and you use `,]$score <- 10` then you're trying to assign a value into "nothing" since the `grep` is going to return an `integer(0)` and the data frame subset will attempt to reference the `score` variable. `grepl` just returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` for all the rows and if none of the boolean values return `TRUE` it won't attempt to reference `,"score"]`. Using `$score` vs `, `,"score"]` with `grepl` would forces it to reference `score` even if there are no matches, so it needs to be within the bracketed subset syntax.